# Sending custom commands to embedded device over LAN: characters or ints?

Tags: c++, networking, embedded, state-machine

I'm working on firmware that will be able to receive commands from a PC application and had planned to use characters to do this, but when defining them in my header, I accidentally put `'` instead of `"` which made it define an int. That got me thinking as to the differences between the two. If I was to use an int, I would be able to compare the command more quickly, rather than cycle through the multiple characters in my command. However I'm unsure if there are other issues I might run into. I'm also working in a state machine, and will have one or more switch statements.

What difference is there between int and character when sending and receiving over a network?

An example command: `#define POWER_OFF "PWROFF"`

EDIT: Using the GCC ARM compiler, if that helps. I'm also expecting to have over 60 commands. I'll be able to manipulate outputs and switching modes.

Comment: "cycle through the multiple characters in my command" do you actually mean "strings or ints" ? A character is only a single character, nothing to cycle through ;)

Comment: btw no matter what you choose, you shouldnt use `#define`. Among (many) other problems `#define` does not really "define" anything but merely replaces text in your code before it gets compiled

Comment: It would be a char array.

Comment: You can fast out of "PWROFF" (and similar commands) oftentimes.  So you maybe don't ALWAYS have to read all the chars.  Can you tell the length of the string? (It starts with 'P', its length is 6, maybe you can tell its "PWROFF" and not "PWRON" or "PWRCYCLE" ??).   I tend to think the readability / extensibility of strings for future maintenance of this code makes them worth the extra pico-cost

Comment: Also, there would be a lot of different commands that I would have. I'm not sure of another clean way other than using defines. I could use enums, but I haven't really thought much about it.

Comment: @NeilGatenby I probably won't have more than 10 characters to a command.

Comment: Use strings/char arrays, and use `const string power_off = "PWROFF";` or `const char power_off[] = "PWROFF";`, not macros. Readability and maintainability is way more valuable that few cycles you are going to save for not comparing some more characters. Also, in the future, you may want to create a command line interface to communicate with your device using typed commands, just like in a shell.

Comment: I prefer to use [Nanopb](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb) embedded Protobuf implementation to simplify a protocol design with the benefit of portability between programming languages and target device/OS platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a lot on the CPU of your embedded device and also the frequency of message exchanges. Because you are using LAN (and not RS232 or TTL), the bandwidth is not to be considered. To achieve more code readability and easier maintenance and also ability to test the embedded device easily, it is better to design your message protocol on ASCII mode (characters) than binary mode (numbers and byte-commands), unless you have frequent iteration of commands send to a CPU with low processing capability. The other suitable way is to use ASCII for command titles and use binary for operands and arguments (if any).